# javascript-window and cfform

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfform

I have Parent page and a Child page('empW.cfm'),which is nothing but a popup window on one of the form fields on Parent page. I am using `<cfform>` in the Parent page. I want to populate the data from this Child-page-popup-window, to that related form field in Parent -page.
Tried all means but no success till now.

Parent page:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" >

    function doSubmit() {
      var Emp = document.getElementById("emp");
      var getName = document.getElementById("getName");
      Emp.value = getName.value;
                }
           </script> 
</head>
<body>
<cfajaximport tags="cfform,cfwindow">
<cfform action="Action.cfm" name="formE" id="formE" preserveData="true"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(document.formE);"  >  
 <table >
    <tbody>    
            <tr><td  > Name*: </td><td><cfinput name="Name" id="Name"  type="text"  ></td></tr>          

             <tr><td > EMP:</td>

     <td><input name="searchName" id="emp"   onClick="createWindow('empW.cfm')"></td>
    </tr>  
   </tbody>
 </table>
</cfform>
```

Child/Window page:-

```
<!--- empW.cfm --->
<cfform name="formI" id="formI" preserveData="false" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr><td>
  <cfif isdefined('form.getName')>
   <cfoutput>Selected = #form.getName#!</cfoutput>
  <cfelse>
   Selected =
  </cfif>
 </td></tr>
 <tr>
  <input name="getName" id="getName" type="text" value="Find emp name" >
  <input name="Add" id="getName" type="submit" onChange="doSubmit();">
 </td></tr>
 </table>
</cfform>
```

Please help.

Comment: You obviously need to edit your question. It's unclear are you talking about different templates, popup, modal winowds or something else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main page code:

`<td><input name="searchName" id="emp" onclick="ColdFusion.Window.create('w1','Title','empW.cfm')"></td>`

empW.cfm page code:

`<input name="Add" id="getName" type="button" value="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('emp').value=document.getElementById('getName').value;">`

Also remove `src` attribute from parent page's script code.

In empW.cfm page, submit button's `onChange()` will be never called as `submit()` event will be called first and therefore you lost `onChange()` event.

Comment: Thanks Vikas! But was wondering what is the need of "W1" and "Title"

Comment: in main page code...Onclick="document... ('w1','Title','empW.cfm')"

Comment: See the syntax here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fbf.html

Comment: when i followed Vikas suggestion <input name="Add" id="getName" type="button" value="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('emp').value=document.getElementById('getName').">  is working but...

Comment: am able to pass only the first value from the given results of #form.getName#!.

Comment: i mean from a list of 10 results only the first result is being passed

Comment: even if other results are selected

Comment: You can use jquery, `$('#getName option:selected').text();`